# intercept field access to log with bytebuddy

Tags: byte-buddy

I am trying to log field writes with bytebuddy. After reading some earlier posts, I started using `MemberSubstitution` and got something going using the following code:

```
private static Method FIELD_INTERCEPTOR = // reflective reference to interceptFieldWrite
AsmVisitorWrapper VISITOR = MemberSubstitution.relaxed()
  .field(ElementMatchers.any())
  .onWrite()
  .replaceWith(FIELD_INTERCEPTOR)
  .on(ElementMatchers.isMethod());
..
public static void interceptFieldWrite(Object object,Object value) {
   System.out.println("intercepted field write in object " + object + " , attempt to set value to " + value);
}
..
```

The part I am struggling with is how to pass a reference to the field for which the access is intercepted to `interceptFieldWrite` (as string or instance of `Field`). If possible I would of course like to avoid reflection completely. I don't actually want to completely substitute field access, but just want to add a method with some checks just before it takes place. Is there a feature in bytebuddy to do this, or do I have to use something more low-level than ASM to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Byte Buddy offers this but you will have to compose your own `StackManipulation`s to do so. The mechanism in `MemberSubstitution` is called `replaceWithChain`. Here you specify `Step`s where each step can do what you intend:

- invoke a method via `MethodInvocation`.
- write a field via `FieldAccessor`.

You will have to load the arguments to the method call and the field access prior to using the above stack manipulations via the `MethodVariableAccess` where the targeted element's offsets are represented by `offsets`.

In your case, this would require to read the target instance via

```
MethodVaribaleAccess.of(parameters.get(0)).loadFrom(offsets.get(0));
MethodVaribaleAccess.of(parameters.get(1)).loadFrom(offsets.get(1));
```

and the to execute the method or field write in question. The targeted field will be passed as `target`, you can cast it to `FieldDescription` if you only ever intercept fields.

Make sure you only intercept non-static fields where the *this* instance will not be passed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, much appreciated. I had a look at some code examples and tests.  I am struggling with instantiating ```MemberSubstitution.Substitution.Chain.Step``` as ```Step``` is protected. Is there a way to use this (other than using ```Simple```) ?

Comment: That's an embarrassing oversight, yes the interface is supposed to be public, of course. I will fix this in the next release. This gives a good real-life indication on how much the step feature is used, too...